# meaning of the uninstallation sentence?

Tags: translation, software

Please, what is the meaning of this sentence? is it chinese, right?

[image]

I am truing to uninstall software OSToto to create a wifi hotspot. The software switched from English to Chinese by its own, and I am unable to uninstall it. Neither, to copy the sentence and translate it through the google translator. Please, what is the meaning of the printscreen?

Thank you !

Comment: 卸载程序无法执行，可能是卸载所需的数据被破坏！
the uninstall procedure cannot be performed, maybe the data needed for uninstalling have been ruined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

卸载程序无法执行，可能是卸载所需的数据被破坏！

I prefer to translate it as:

> The system has failed to launch the uninstallation process. This might be caused by the loss/destroy of some data which is required (for uninstalling it).

BTW, it's always a nightmare to uninstall applications for Windows. I think maybe you can do some Google research.

Here is one:
http://www.techradar.com/news/software/10-tips-for-removing-a-program-that-won-t-uninstall-907471

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck uninstalling this!